# QuickBooks SDK "ticket parameter is invalid" error

Tags: exception, qbxml

We have an order import app that has been in production for 3 months. 2 weeks ago we started getting intermittent "invalid ticket parameter" exceptions. What does this mean and how can we fix it?

We get it on various requests: customer and item queries, sales order inserts, etc. Most of the time these calls work fine but every so often one of them will kick out an exception. Here's an example from our log:

```xml
2014/03/20 13:11:28.222 - Error in QB.ExecuteRequests(IMsgSetRequest): Exception: The ticket parameter is invalid.
2014/03/20 13:11:28.222 - Error in QB.ExecuteRequests(IMsgSetRequest): RequestXML: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError">
<ItemQueryRq requestID = "0">
  <NameFilter>
    <MatchCriterion>Contains</MatchCriterion>
    <Name>01507</Name>
  </NameFilter>
  <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
</ItemQueryRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Any ideas? QBSDK v12 with QBES 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Enable verbose logging and see if the logs tell you anything. https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/177198-troubleshooting-sdk-issues